# cs 1.6 installation linux weirdness

Tags: linux

```
root@xxx:/# mkdir hlds
root@xxx:/# cd hlds/
root@xxxx:/hlds# wget http://www.cstrike-planet.com/dls/hldsupdatetool.bin
--2014-01-04 06:31:38--  http://www.cstrike-planet.com/dls/hldsupdatetool.bin
Resolving www.cstrike-planet.com (www.cstrike-planet.com)... 64.237.53.18
Connecting to www.cstrike-planet.com (www.cstrike-planet.com)|64.237.53.18|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3513408 (3.4M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: `hldsupdatetool.bin'

100%[================================================================================================================================================================>] 3,513,408   --.-K/s   in 0.1s    

2014-01-04 06:31:38 (27.4 MB/s) - `hldsupdatetool.bin' saved [3513408/3513408]

root@xxxx:/hlds# cd hlds/
-bash: cd: hlds/: No such file or directory
root@xxxx:/hlds# chmod a+x hldsupdatetool.bin 
root@xxxx:/hlds# ./hldsupdatetool.bin 
-bash: ./hldsupdatetool.bin: No such file or directory
root@xxxx:/hlds# ls -hal hldsupdatetool.bin 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.4M May 12  2005 hldsupdatetool.bin
root@xxxx:/hlds#
```

Q: how there is no such file??? Can somebody please explain? these command counter false each other?

Comment: This is a **programming** Q&A site, not support for installing a video game :|

Comment: Also, googling "hldsupdatetool", which you should try, indicates that tool was deprecated in 2013 in favour of [SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That file you just referenced is a 32-bit binary. The error "No such file or directory" can actually occur when the file you're executing exists, but a library on which it depends doesn't!

Seeing it's a 32-bit binary. My guess is you're on a 64-bit system and have no 32-bit libraries. Try installing the 32-bit version of libc. In Debian and friends you can do this by

```
sudo apt-get install libc:i386
```

EDIT: And by the way, you have a perfectly valid question but the title is just plain off-topic. Try to write something more to the point, and not mentioning the game since it doesn't matter at all.